# Dynamic Column in DataTable depending on user input in Primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces

**Code:**

**search.xhtml**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:form id="form">
    <h:body>
    <h:outputLabel value="Kiosk Id"> </h:outputLabel>
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{abacusMB.kioskId}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="-Select-" itemValue="null"></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1001" itemValue="1001"></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1002" itemValue="1002"></f:selectItem>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <br></br>
    <h:outputLabel value="Kiosk Location"></h:outputLabel>
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{abacusMB.location}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="-Select-" itemValue="null"></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Nashik" itemValue="Nashik"></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Lonavala" itemValue="Lonavala"></f:selectItem>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <br></br>
    <center>
    <p:commandButton value="Search" type="submit" actionListener="#{abacusMB.searchRecord}" update="seachResult"></p:commandButton>
    </center>
    <p:dataTable id="seachResult" rendered="#{abacusMB.recordFlag}" lazy="true" value="#{abacusMB.recordList}" var="record">
    <p:column headerText="User">
    <h:outputText value="#{record.userName}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="KioskId">
    <h:outputText value="#{record.kioskId}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Location">
    <h:outputText value="#{record.location}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    </h:body>
    </h:form>
    </html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Abacus</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bluesky</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

**RecordVO.java**

```
    package com.abacus.search.vo;

    import java.io.Serializable;


    public class RecordVO implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 11L;
        private String location;
        private String kioskId;
        private String userName;

        public String getLocation() {
            return location;
        }

        public void setLocation(String location) {
            this.location = location;
        }

        public String getKioskId() {
            return kioskId;
        }

        public void setKioskId(String kioskId) {
            this.kioskId = kioskId;
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }
    }
```

**AbacusMB.java**

```
    package com.abacus.search.managedbean;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import com.abacus.search.vo.RecordVO;
    public class AbacusMB implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String location;
        private String kioskId;
        private boolean recordFlag;
        private List<RecordVO>recordList=new ArrayList<RecordVO>();

        public String getLocation() {
            return location;
        }

        public void setLocation(String location) {
            this.location = location;
        }

        public String getKioskId() {
            return kioskId;
        }

        public void setKioskId(String kioskId) {
            this.kioskId = kioskId;
        }

        public boolean isRecordFlag() {
            return recordFlag;
        }

        public void setRecordFlag(boolean recordFlag) {
            this.recordFlag = recordFlag;
        }

        public List<RecordVO> getRecordList() {
            return recordList;
        }

        public void setRecordList(List<RecordVO> recordList) {
            this.recordList = recordList;
        }
        public void searchRecord(){
            recordFlag=true;
            List<RecordVO> recordVOTempList=new ArrayList<RecordVO>();

            if(this.kioskId.equals("1001") && this.location.equals("Nashik")){
                System.out.println("User has selected kiosk id as 1001 and location as Nashik ");
                System.out.println("We will display two records to Nashik");
                for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
                    if(i==0){
                        RecordVO recordVO=new RecordVO();
                        recordVO.setKioskId(kioskId);
                        recordVO.setLocation(location);
                        recordVO.setUserName("Sumit");
                        recordVOTempList.add(recordVO);
                    }else{
                        RecordVO recordVO=new RecordVO();
                        recordVO.setKioskId(kioskId);
                        recordVO.setLocation(location);
                        recordVO.setUserName("Aniket");
                        recordVOTempList.add(recordVO);
                        }
                }

            }else{
                if(this.kioskId.equals("1002") && this.location.equals("Lonavala")){
                    System.out.println("User has selected kiosk id as 1002 and location as Lonavala ");
                    System.out.println("We will display two records to Lonavala");
                    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
                        if(i==0){
                            RecordVO recordVO=new RecordVO();
                            recordVO.setKioskId(kioskId);
                            recordVO.setLocation(location);
                            recordVO.setUserName("Aarti");
                            recordVOTempList.add(recordVO);
                        }else{
                            RecordVO recordVO=new RecordVO();
                            recordVO.setKioskId(kioskId);
                            recordVO.setLocation(location);
                            recordVO.setUserName("Rachana");
                            recordVOTempList.add(recordVO);
                            }
                    }//close for loop

                }//close if loop
            }//close else
            System.out.println("Record Flag value:"+recordFlag);
            System.out.println("Temp List size="+recordVOTempList.size());
            this.recordList=recordVOTempList;

        }

    }//close class
```

Suppose user inputs only location and doesn't give any input for kiosk id  then in displayed records after clicking on search button the kiosk id column should not be displayed.

How to implement this?

One solution I am thinking is I will check for each input whether its value is null or not and depending on that i will rendered corresponding columns.
Tell me whether it is correct or not?
My bean is in view scope.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>  
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" /></h:head>  

 <h:body>  

 <h:form id="form">
    <p:graphicImage value="images/Abacus.jpg" width="100%"></p:graphicImage> 
    <p:tabView id="tabView">  

    <p:tab id="tab1" title="Dashboard">  
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  

        </h:panelGrid>  
    </p:tab>  

    <p:tab id="tab2" title="Search">  
    <center>
        <p:outputLabel value="Search Report" styleClass="sumit" ></p:outputLabel>
    </center>
    <p:panel> 

     <p:panelGrid columns="4" style="width:100%" >  

     <h:outputLabel value="Transaction Id:  " />  
       <p:inputMask value="#{abacusMB.transactionId}" mask="9999999999999999"> </p:inputMask>

     <h:outputLabel  value="Service Type:  " />  
       <p:selectOneMenu value="#{abacusMB.serviceType}">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="-Select-"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Deposit" itemValue="Deposit"></f:selectItem>  
       </p:selectOneMenu>  

     <h:outputLabel  value="Account Number:  " />  
       <p:inputMask value="#{abacusMB.accountNumber}" mask="9999999999999999"> </p:inputMask> 

     <h:outputLabel  value="Account Type:  " />  
       <p:selectOneMenu value="#{abacusMB.accountType}">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="ALL" itemValue="ALL"  />
            <f:selectItems  value="#{abacusMB.accTypes}"></f:selectItems>

       </p:selectOneMenu>  

    <h:outputLabel  value="Kiosk Location:  " />  
       <p:selectOneMenu value="#{abacusMB.kioskLocation}" >  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="ALL" itemValue="ALL"  />  
            <f:selectItems value="#{abacusMB.kioskLocations}"/> 
            <p:ajax listener="#{abacusMB.onSelectLocation}" update="namelist"></p:ajax> 
       </p:selectOneMenu>   

       <h:outputLabel  value="Deposit Mode:  " />  
       <p:selectOneMenu value="#{abacusMB.depositMode}">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="-Select-"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cash" itemValue="Cash"></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cheque" itemValue="Cheque"></f:selectItem>  
       </p:selectOneMenu>  

     <h:outputLabel  value="Kiosk Name:  " />  
       <p:selectOneMenu value="#{abacusMB.kioskName}" disabled="#{abacusMB.kioName}" id="namelist">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="ALL" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItems value="#{abacusMB.kname}" />  
            <p:ajax listener="#{abacusMB.onSelectName}" update="idlist"></p:ajax>
       </p:selectOneMenu>

     <h:outputLabel  value="Transaction Status:  " />  
       <p:selectOneMenu value="#{abacusMB.transactionStatus}">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="ALL" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Failed" itemValue="Failed" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Success" itemValue="Success" />  
       </p:selectOneMenu>

    <h:outputLabel  value="Kiosk Id:  " />  
     <p:selectOneMenu value="#{abacusMB.kioskId}" disabled="#{abacusMB.kioId}" id="idlist">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="ALL" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItems value="#{abacusMB.kid}" />  
     </p:selectOneMenu>

     <h:outputLabel  value="Batch Id:  " />  
     <p:selectOneMenu value="#{abacusMB.batchId}">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="ALL" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItems value="#{abacusMB.bid}" />  
     </p:selectOneMenu>

    <h:outputLabel  value="Start Date: " />
        <p:calendar value="#{abacusMB.startDate}" showOn="button" size="10" >  
    </p:calendar> 

    <h:outputLabel value="End Date: " />
       <p:calendar value="#{abacusMB.endDate}" showOn="button" size="10" required="true" requiredMessage="Please select End Date">  
    </p:calendar>    

     <h:outputLabel value="Get All Data:"></h:outputLabel>
      <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{abacusMB.searchAll}" immediate="true" />
  </p:panelGrid>   
</p:panel> 

<center>
  <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Search" icon="ui-icon-check" style="margin:0" action="#{abacusMB.getSearchSubmit}" update=":form:datatbl" immediate="true"/> 
</center>
<br/><br/>
<p:dataTable  var="itr" value="#{abacusMB.searchReportList}"  rendered="#{abacusMB.showSearch}" id="datatbl" lazy="true" paginator="true" rows="5"  
                 paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"  
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" emptyMessage="No Records Found!!!">


<p:column headerText="Transaction ID"/>
<h:outputText value="#{itr.transId}" ></h:outputText>
<p:column headerText="Kiosk ID"/>
<h:outputText value="#{itr.kioskId}" ></h:outputText>
<p:column headerText="Account Number"/>
<h:outputText value="#{itr.accNumber}" ></h:outputText>
<p:column headerText="Transaction Code"/>
<h:outputText value="#{itr.transCode}" ></h:outputText>
<p:column headerText="Deposite Mode"/>
<h:outputText value="#{itr.depoMode}" ></h:outputText>
<p:column headerText="Deposite Amount"/>
<h:outputText value="#{itr.depoAmt}" ></h:outputText>
<p:column headerText="Denomination"/>
<h:outputText value="#{itr.denomination}" ></h:outputText>
<p:column headerText="Checque Number"/>
<h:outputText value="#{itr.chkNumber}" ></h:outputText>
<p:column headerText="MICR Code"/>
<h:outputText value="#{itr.micrCode}" ></h:outputText>
<p:column headerText="Note Count"/>
<h:outputText value="#{itr.noteCnt}" ></h:outputText>
<p:column headerText="Batch ID"/>
<h:outputText value="#{itr.batchId}" ></h:outputText>
<p:column headerText="Date"/>
<h:outputText value="#{itr.dt}" ></h:outputText>
<p:column headerText="Time"/>
<h:outputText value="#{itr.tym}" ></h:outputText>
<p:column headerText="Service Type"/>
<h:outputText value="#{itr.serviceType}" ></h:outputText>
<p:column headerText="Account Type"/>
<h:outputText value="#{itr.accType}" ></h:outputText>
<p:column headerText="Kiosk Name"/>
<h:outputText value="#{itr.kioskName}" ></h:outputText>
<p:column headerText="City"/>
<h:outputText value="#{itr.city}" ></h:outputText>
<p:column headerText="State"/>
<h:outputText value="#{itr.state}" ></h:outputText>
<p:column headerText="Country"/>
<h:outputText value="#{itr.country}" ></h:outputText>

</p:dataTable>

    </p:tab>  

    <p:tab id="tab3" title="Monthly Report">  
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
        </h:panelGrid>  
    </p:tab>  
  <p:tab id="tab4" title="EOD Report">  
<center>
    <p:outputLabel value="EOD Summary Report" styleClass="sumit" ></p:outputLabel></center>
  <p:panel> 
          <p:panelGrid columns="4" style="width:100%" >  
        <h:outputLabel value="Kiosk Circle:  " />  
     <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="selectMenu">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="ALL" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3" />  
        </p:selectOneMenu>  
         <h:outputLabel  value="Payment Mode:  " />  
     <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="selectMenu">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="ALL" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3" />  
        </p:selectOneMenu>  
         <h:outputLabel  value="Kiosk Name:  " />

     <p:selectOneMenu value="#{abacusMB.userName}" styleClass="selectMenu">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="ALL" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItems value="#{abacusMB.users}"></f:selectItems>
        </p:selectOneMenu>  
     <h:outputLabel  value="Batch Id:  " />  
     <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="selectMenu">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="ALL" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3" />  
        </p:selectOneMenu>
     <h:outputLabel  value="Service:  " />  
     <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="selectMenu">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="ALL" itemValue=""  />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3" />  
      </p:selectOneMenu>
      <h:outputLabel  value="Start Date: " />
       <p:calendar value="#{abacusMB.startDate}" showOn="button" size="10" >  
    </p:calendar> 
    <h:outputLabel value="End Date: " />
       <p:calendar value="#{abacusMB.startDate}" showOn="button" size="10" required="true" requiredMessage="Please select End Date">  
    </p:calendar>    

</p:panelGrid> </p:panel> 

<center>
  <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Search" icon="ui-icon-check" style="margin:0" action="#{abacusMB.getEODReport}" update="@form" immediate="true"/> 

</center>
</p:tab>  
  <p:tab id="tab5" title="Custom View">  
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
        </h:panelGrid>  
    </p:tab>  
   <p:tab id="tab7" title="Log Off">  
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
        </h:panelGrid>  
    </p:tab>  

</p:tabView>  

<p:panel id="Results">
<p:dataTable value="#{abacusMB.eodReport}" var="itr" rendered="true" emptyMessage="No Records Found!!!" id="record">
<p:column headerText="Kiosk Circle"/>
<h:outputText value="#{itr.circle}" ></h:outputText>
<p:column headerText="Kiosk Name"/>
<h:outputText value="#{eod.getName}"></h:outputText>
<p:column headerText="Kiosk Service"/>
<h:outputText value="#{eod.service}"></h:outputText>
</p:dataTable>
</p:panel>
 </h:form>  
 </h:body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

BeanClass for it

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.everest.managedbean;


//use control+alt+o for auto package update
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.event.DateSelectEvent;

import com.everest.dao.DbManager;
import com.everest.vo.ResultVO;


import com.everest.vo.SearchVO;


/**
 * @author ANIKET
 *
 */
public class AbacusMB implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String accountNumber;
    private String accountType;
    private List<String>accTypes;
    private String transactionId;
    private String serviceType;
    private String kioskLocation;
    private List<String> kioskLocations;
    private String kioskId;
    private List<String>kid;
    private boolean kioId=true;
    private String batchId;
    private List<String>bid;
    private String depositMode;
    private String kioskName;
    private List<String>kname;
    private boolean kioName=true;
    private String transactionStatus;
    private String userName;
    private List<String>users;

    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;

    private List<ResultVO>eodReport;
    private boolean showEOD=false;

    private List<SearchVO>searchReportList;
    private boolean showSearch=false;
    private boolean searchAll=false;

    DbManager db=DbManager.getDbobject();
    Statement stmt;

    public AbacusMB() {
        this.eodReport=new ArrayList<ResultVO>();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    /**
     * @return the users
     * @throws SQLException 
     */
    public List<String> getUsers() throws SQLException {

//        stmt=db.con.createStatement();
//        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from abacus_user");
//        users=new ArrayList<String>();
//        while(rs.next())
//        {
//          users.add(rs.getString("name"));
//        }

        return users;
    }

    /**
     * @param users the users to set
     */
    public void setUsers(List<String> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    /**
     * @return the userName
     */
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    /**
     * @param userName the userName to set
     */
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
     public void handleDateSelect(DateSelectEvent event) {  
            FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");  
            facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Date Selected", format.format(event.getDate())));  
     }

    /**
     * @return the startDate
     */
    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param startDate the startDate to set
     */
    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return the endDate
     */
    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param endDate the endDate to set
     */
    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }  
    public void getEODReport(){
    eodReport=new ArrayList<ResultVO>();
    System.out.println("Inside EOD Report");
    showEOD=true;
    ResultVO r1=new ResultVO();
    r1.setCircle("Gangapur Naka");
    r1.setName("Airtel");
    r1.setService("PrePaid");
    ResultVO r2=new ResultVO();
    r1.setCircle("Sanghvi");
    r1.setName("TataDocomo");
    r1.setService("PostPaid");
    eodReport.add(r1);
    eodReport.add(r2);
    this.setEodReport(eodReport);
    System.out.println("Size of eodReportVO: "+eodReport.size());
    }

    /**
     * @return the eodReport
     */
    public List<ResultVO> getEodReport() {

        return eodReport;
    }

    /**
     * @param eodReport the eodReport to set
     */
    public void setEodReport(List<ResultVO> eodReport) {
        this.eodReport = eodReport;
    }

    /**
     * @return the showEOD
     */
    public boolean isShowEOD() {
        return showEOD;
    }

    /**
     * @param showEOD the showEOD to set
     */
    public void setShowEOD(boolean showEOD) {
        this.showEOD = showEOD;
    }

    /**
     * @return the depositMode
     */
    public String getDepositMode() {
        return depositMode;
    }

    /**
     * @param depositMode the depositMode to set
     */
    public void setDepositMode(String depositMode) {
        this.depositMode = depositMode;
    }


    /**
     * @param serviceType the serviceType to set
     */
    public void setServiceType(String serviceType) {
        this.serviceType = serviceType;
    }

    /**
     * @return the serviceType
     */
    public String getServiceType() {
        return serviceType;
    }

    /**
     * @return the searchAll
     */
    public boolean isSearchAll() {
        return searchAll;
    }

    /**
     * @param searchAll the searchAll to set
     */
    public void setSearchAll(boolean searchAll) {
        this.searchAll = searchAll;
        if(searchAll){
            System.out.println("Get All Data is selected");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Get All Data is not selected");
        }
    }
    /**
     * @return the accountNumber
     */
    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @param accountNumber the accountNumber to set
     */
    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @return the kioskLocation
     */
    public String getKioskLocation() {
        return kioskLocation;
    }
    /**
     * @param kioskLocation the kioskLocation to set
     */
    public void setKioskLocation(String kioskLocation) {
        this.kioskLocation = kioskLocation;
    }
    /**
     * This list is used ton populate Kiosk Location dropdown list
     * @return the kioskLocations
     * @throws SQLException 
     */
    public List<String> getKioskLocations() throws SQLException {

        kioskLocations=new ArrayList<String>();
        stmt=db.con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select city from kiosk_master_tbl");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            kioskLocations.add(rs.getString(1));
        }
        return kioskLocations;
    }
    /**
     * @param kioskLocations the kioskLocations to set
     */
    public void setKioskLocations(List<String> kioskLocations) {
        this.kioskLocations = kioskLocations;
    }
    /**
     * @return the transactionStatus
     */
    public String getTransactionStatus() {
        return transactionStatus;
    }
    /**
     * @param transactionStatus the transactionStatus to set
     */
    public void setTransactionStatus(String transactionStatus) {
        this.transactionStatus = transactionStatus;
    }

    /**
     * @return the accTypes
     */
    public List<String> getAccTypes() {
        accTypes=new ArrayList<String>();
            accTypes.add("Saving");
            accTypes.add("Current");

        return accTypes;
    }
    /**
     * @param accTypes the accTypes to set
     */
    public void setAccTypes(List<String> accTypes) {
        this.accTypes = accTypes;
    }
    /**
     * @return the accountType
     */
    public String getAccountType() {
        return accountType;
    }
    /**
     * @param accountType the accountType to set
     */
    public void setAccountType(String accountType) {
        this.accountType = accountType;
    }
    /**
     * @return the kioskName
     */
    public String getKioskName() {
        return kioskName;
    }
    /**
     * @param kioskName the kioskName to set
     */
    public void setKioskName(String kioskName) {
        this.kioskName = kioskName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the kname
     * @throws SQLException 
     */
    public List<String> getKname() throws SQLException {


        return kname;
    }
    /**
     * @param kname the kname to set
     */
    public void setKname(List<String> kname) {
        this.kname = kname;
    }

    /**
     * @return the transactionId
     */
    public String getTransactionId() {
        return transactionId;
    }
    /**
     * @param transactionId the transactionId to set
     */
    public void setTransactionId(String transactionId) {
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the kioskId
     */
    public String getKioskId() {
        return kioskId;
    }
    /**
     * @param kioskId the kioskId to set
     */
    public void setKioskId(String kioskId) {
        this.kioskId = kioskId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the kid
     * @throws SQLException 
     */
    public List<String> getKid() throws SQLException {


        return kid;
    }
    /**
     * @param kid the kid to set
     */
    public void setKid(List<String> kid) {
        this.kid = kid;
    }
    /**
     * @return the batchId
     */
    public String getBatchId() {
        return batchId;
    }
    /**
     * @param batchId the batchId to set
     */
    public void setBatchId(String batchId) {
        this.batchId = batchId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the bid
     * @throws SQLException 
     */
    public List<String> getBid() throws SQLException {
        bid=new ArrayList<String>();
        stmt=db.con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select batchid from batch_info_tbl");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            bid.add(rs.getString(1));
        }
        return bid;
    }
    /**
     * @param bid the bid to set
     */
    public void setBid(List<String> bid) {
        this.bid = bid;
    }
    public void setKioName(boolean kioName) {
        this.kioName = kioName;
    }
    public boolean isKioName() {
        return kioName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the kioId
     */
    public boolean isKioId() {
        return kioId;
    }
    /**
     * @param kioId the kioId to set
     */
    public void setKioId(boolean kioId) {
        this.kioId = kioId;
    }

    public void onSelectLocation() throws SQLException
    {
        if(kioskLocation!=null)
        {
            kioName=false;
            kname=new ArrayList<String>();
            stmt=db.con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select kioskname from kiosk_master_tbl where city='"+kioskLocation+"'" );
            while(rs.next())
            {
                kname.add(rs.getString(1));
            }
        }
    }

    public void onSelectName() throws SQLException
    {
        if(kioskName!=null)
        {
            kioId=false;
            stmt=db.con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select kioskid from kiosk_master_tbl where kioskname='"+kioskName+"'");
            kid=new ArrayList<String>();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                kid.add(rs.getString(1));
            }
        }
    }

    public void getSearchSubmit() throws SQLException
    {
        int i=0;
        System.out.println("Inside search");
        showSearch=true;
        stmt=db.con.createStatement();
        searchReportList=new ArrayList<SearchVO>();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM (SELECT ct.transactionid,ct.kioskid,ct.AccountNumber,ct.TransactionCode,ct.DepositeMode,ct.DepositeAmount,ct.Denomination,ct.ChequeNumber,ct.MICRCode,ct.NoteCount,ct.BatchId,ct.Dt,ct.Tym,ct.ServiceType,ct.AccountType,kmt.kioskname,kmt.city,kmt.state,kmt.country FROM kiosk_master_tbl AS kmt ,customer_transaction AS ct WHERE ct.kioskid=kmt.kioskid) AS newtbl WHERE newtbl.AccountType='"+accountType+"' ");

        while(rs.next())
        {
            i++;
            SearchVO vo=new SearchVO();

            vo.setTransId(rs.getString(1));
            vo.setKioskId(rs.getString(2));
            vo.setAccNumber(rs.getString(3));
            vo.setTransCode(rs.getString(4));
            vo.setDepoMode(rs.getString(5));
            vo.setDepoAmt(rs.getString(6));
            vo.setDenomination(rs.getString(7));
            vo.setChkNumber(rs.getString(8));
            vo.setMicrCode(rs.getString(9));
            vo.setNoteCnt(rs.getString(10));
            vo.setBatchId(rs.getString(11));
            vo.setDt(rs.getString(12));
            vo.setTym(rs.getString(13));
            vo.setServiceType(rs.getString(14));
            vo.setAccType(rs.getString(15));
            vo.setKioskName(rs.getString(16));
            vo.setCity(rs.getString(17));
            vo.setState(rs.getString(18));
            vo.setCountry(rs.getString(19));
            searchReportList.add(vo);
        }
        this.setSearchReportList(searchReportList);
        System.out.println("No. Of Record:- "+i);
        System.out.println("Size of SearchVO: "+searchReportList.size());
    }
    /**
     * @return the showSearch
     */
    public boolean isShowSearch() {
        return showSearch;
    }
    /**
     * @param showSearch the showSearch to set
     */
    public void setShowSearch(boolean showSearch) {
        this.showSearch = showSearch;
    }
    /**
     * @return the searchReportList
     */
    public List<SearchVO> getSearchReportList() {
        return searchReportList;
    }
    /**
     * @param searchReportList the searchReportList to set
     */
    public void setSearchReportList(List<SearchVO> searchReportList) {
        this.searchReportList = searchReportList;
    }
}
```

// Style Class

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
.sumit{
color:blue; 
}

.selectCalendarMenu{
width:50%;  
}
```

//ValueObject Class

```
public class SearchVO implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String transId;
    private String kioskId;
    private String accNumber;
    private String transCode;
    private String depoMode;
    private String depoAmt;
    private String denomination;
    private String chkNumber;
    private String micrCode;
    private String noteCnt;
    private String batchId;
    private String serviceType;
    private String accType;
    private String kioskName;
    private String dt;
    private String tym;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String country;
    /**
     * @return the transId
     */
    public String getTransId() {
        return transId;
    }
    /**
     * @param transId the transId to set
     */
    public void setTransId(String transId) {
        this.transId = transId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the kioskId
     */
    public String getKioskId() {
        return kioskId;
    }
    /**
     * @param kioskId the kioskId to set
     */
    public void setKioskId(String kioskId) {
        this.kioskId = kioskId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the accNumber
     */
    public String getAccNumber() {
        return accNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @param accNumber the accNumber to set
     */
    public void setAccNumber(String accNumber) {
        this.accNumber = accNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @return the transCode
     */
    public String getTransCode() {
        return transCode;
    }
    /**
     * @param transCode the transCode to set
     */
    public void setTransCode(String transCode) {
        this.transCode = transCode;
    }
    /**
     * @return the depoMode
     */
    public String getDepoMode() {
        return depoMode;
    }
    /**
     * @param depoMode the depoMode to set
     */
    public void setDepoMode(String depoMode) {
        this.depoMode = depoMode;
    }
    /**
     * @return the depoAmt
     */
    public String getDepoAmt() {
        return depoAmt;
    }
    /**
     * @param depoAmt the depoAmt to set
     */
    public void setDepoAmt(String depoAmt) {
        this.depoAmt = depoAmt;
    }
    /**
     * @return the denomination
     */
    public String getDenomination() {
        return denomination;
    }
    /**
     * @param denomination the denomination to set
     */
    public void setDenomination(String denomination) {
        this.denomination = denomination;
    }
    /**
     * @return the chkNumber
     */
    public String getChkNumber() {
        return chkNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @param chkNumber the chkNumber to set
     */
    public void setChkNumber(String chkNumber) {
        this.chkNumber = chkNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @return the micrCode
     */
    public String getMicrCode() {
        return micrCode;
    }
    /**
     * @param micrCode the micrCode to set
     */
    public void setMicrCode(String micrCode) {
        this.micrCode = micrCode;
    }
    /**
     * @return the noteCnt
     */
    public String getNoteCnt() {
        return noteCnt;
    }
    /**
     * @param noteCnt the noteCnt to set
     */
    public void setNoteCnt(String noteCnt) {
        this.noteCnt = noteCnt;
    }
    /**
     * @return the batchId
     */
    public String getBatchId() {
        return batchId;
    }
    /**
     * @param batchId the batchId to set
     */
    public void setBatchId(String batchId) {
        this.batchId = batchId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the serviceType
     */
    public String getServiceType() {
        return serviceType;
    }
    /**
     * @param serviceType the serviceType to set
     */
    public void setServiceType(String serviceType) {
        this.serviceType = serviceType;
    }
    /**
     * @return the accType
     */
    public String getAccType() {
        return accType;
    }
    /**
     * @param accType the accType to set
     */
    public void setAccType(String accType) {
        this.accType = accType;
    }
    /**
     * @return the kioskName
     */
    public String getKioskName() {
        return kioskName;
    }
    /**
     * @param kioskName the kioskName to set
     */
    public void setKioskName(String kioskName) {
        this.kioskName = kioskName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the dt
     */
    public String getDt() {
        return dt;
    }
    /**
     * @param dt the dt to set
     */
    public void setDt(String dt) {
        this.dt = dt;
    }
    /**
     * @return the tym
     */
    public String getTym() {
        return tym;
    }
    /**
     * @param tym the tym to set
     */
    public void setTym(String tym) {
        this.tym = tym;
    }
    /**
     * @return the city
     */
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    /**
     * @param city the city to set
     */
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    /**
     * @return the state
     */
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    /**
     * @param state the state to set
     */
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    /**
     * @return the country
     */
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    /**
     * @param country the country to set
     */
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

}
```